# Learn Python the Hard Way (Exercise 20) has weird symbols when run

Tags: python

Here's the code.

```
from sys import argv

script, input_file = argv

def print_all(f):
    print f.read()

def rewind(f):
    print f.seek(0)

def print_a_line(line_count, f):
    print line_count, f.readline()

current_file = open(input_file)

print "First, we'll print the whole file.\n"

print_all(current_file)

print "Now let's rewind."

rewind(current_file)

print "Let's print three lines."

current_line = 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

And here's the code when run through Terminal (OS X).

```
First, we'll print the whole file.

{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1404\cocoasubrtf470
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0

\f0\fs24 \cf0 example 1\
example 2\
example 3}
Now let's rewind.
None
Let's print three lines.
1 {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1404\cocoasubrtf470

2 {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}

3 {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
```

What seems to be going on here? I even copy and pasted the code from http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex20.html to see if I was doing something wrong but it did the same thing.

Comment: Are you actually reading a plain text file? That looks like some kind of word processor document format or something.

Comment: Also, I can see that you didn't copy-paste the code from the original like you said you did, considering there's an extra `print` in your version.

Comment: I had no idea of that until you pointed it out. Thank you! If you were wondering why the wording in some of the prints were different, it's because I like to have my own personality in them without changing the file too much.

Comment: I don't know why people were down voting you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You edited your file in TextEdit - python is spitting out the bytes that reflect the RTF formatting of the file.  Before saving from TextEdit, choose Format >> Make Text File

Answer (score 0):

You created your input file using a word processor. Use a text editor (Notepad in Windows, I don't know what you'd have in OS X) to create your input file.